Black teens die one by one in a house
Okay, I watched this movie on bet a while ago. It was about a bunch of black teens that are at a house and then one by one they start dying. About the middle of the movie, someone goes for a car and the girl kills him; someone sees it and says it was one of their friends, but at the end it was the girl's twin. At the end the two girls meet but I can't remember what they say. It is probably around 9 or ten years old, maybe more, and English.

I know a movie with a similar plot and will put it up, but please supply more details if you can, at least the approximate year of release & country\language.

Possibly Holla, a horror film from 2006 with a predominantly black cast:

Monica St. John, star of the popular sitcom "Baby Gurl" and her friends head for a weekend including the starlet's boyfriend's ex-con cousin and her agent. When a severe storm moves in and cuts off the power, it becomes a free-for-all of accusations and suspicion as the bodies start to mount. One by one the friends are being murdered. Is it the ex-con cousin? Or the angry agent? Or, is there someone else in the house they don't know about?

...Yes, and it's Monica's deranged twin sister Veronica. Here's the trailer:




Not to be racist is kinda like that but it's a bunch of black teens that are at a house and the twin is killing them. At the end the two girls meet but I can't remember what they say. It is probably around 9 or ten years old maybe more and English. It was on bet.

So the cast is mostly black? (No, I don't think that's racist, it could help with the ID...)

That's all I really know. I can't remember it was so long ago

OK, then, scratch that, I have a better idea. ;) Changing my answer...
